# Anki Droid Image occlusion not working on across 2 or more devices

Tags: android, filesystems, anki

I am using **anki droid** for past few months. Since anki droid don't directly support creation of image occlusion notes (but supports viewing them) I am using external app named 'Anki Image occlusion' to create image occlusions. But sometimes randomly or when i use anki droid across another device by synchronisation, it doesn't work properly
[image: this is the screen i see]